# create source code for CEP in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to create a form in Google Spreadsheet that allow me to write the CEP (Zip code of Brazil), and autocomplete the address, the city, the neighborhood, the State, and a code called IBGE. I'm trying to do it using Apps Script, but I'm not having results.
I used as a guide, the source code of this page (http://viacep.com.br/exemplo/javascript/), and I developed the following script.
*I deleted the SpreeadsheetID for security

```
function myCEP() {
  var spsID = 'deletedforsecurityreasons';
  var sheetN = 'RCA'
  var sps = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spsID);
  var sheet = sps.getSheetByName(sheetN);
  var firstR = 18;
  var lastR = 23;
  var data = sps.getDataRange().getValues();

  for(i in data){
    var row = data[i];
    var cep = sheet.getRange("Z19").getValue();
    var rua = sheet.getRange("I20").getValue();
    var bairro = sheet.getRange("Y21").getValue();
    var cidade = sheet.getRange("H22").getValue();
    var uf = sheet.getRange("X22").getValue();
    var ibge = sheet.getRange("E24").getValue();
    var startRow = 1 + +i;
  }
  function meu_callback(conteudo) {
        if (!("erro" in conteudo)) {
            //Atualiza os campos com os valores.
            sheet.getElementById('rua').setValue=(conteudo.logradouro);
            sheet.getElementById('bairro').set.Value=(conteudo.bairro);
            sheet.getElementById('cidade').set.Value=(conteudo.localidade);
            sheet.getElementById('uf').set.Value=(conteudo.uf);
            sheet.getElementById('ibge').set.Value=(conteudo.ibge);
        } //end if.
        else {
            //CEP não Encontrado.
            sheet.getElementById('rua').value=("CEP não encontrado.");
        }
    }
  function pesquisacep(valor) {
    //Nova variável "cep" somente com dígitos.
    var cep = valor.replace(/\D/g, '');
    //Verifica se campo cep possui valor informado.
    if (cep != "") {
      //Expressão regular para validar o CEP.
      var validacep = /^[0-9]{8}$/;
      //Valida o formato do CEP.
      if(validacep.test(cep)) {
        //Cria um elemento javascript.
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = 'https://viacep.com.br/ws/'+ cep + '/json/?callback=meu_callback';
        document.body.appendChild(script);
            } //end if.
       else {
                //cep é inválido.
                sheet.getElementById('rua').value=("Formato de CEP inválido.");
        }
    };

  }
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```

I do not know if google sheets will allow me to solve this problem, and I do not know if the problem is in the source code syntax. I do not get any results in my form.

Comment: Welcome. Please describe what your code should do and where did you get stuck.

Comment: Possible. But your code is likely unsalvageable. Kindly  practice the [samples](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/)

Answer (score 0):

I'd begin the function like this:

```
function myCEP() {
  var sps = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID');
  var sheet = sps.getSheetByName('RCA');
  var rg=sheet.getRange(18,1,6,sheet.getLastColumn());
  var data = rg.getValues();
```

Unfortunately, I cannot continue since it's not clear at all what your trying to do after that.

Comment: What I want to do is that when I write the CEP, for example: 18053380, in the cell ("Z19") I automatically type in another cell ("I20") the name of the street, in the cell ("Y21") the name from the neighborhood, in the cell ("H22") the name of the city, in the cell ("X22") the name of the state and, finally, in the cell ("E24") the IBGE code. All this information will be extracted from a page ('https://viacep.com.br/ws/'+ cep +' / json /? Callback = meu_callback ')

Is it possible to do something like that?